# How can I make these relative URLs absolute using regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

I need to process CSS files to make any relative paths (using url()) absolute. It should match URIs in single or double quotes, or without quotes. The replacement should not be quoted.

E.g.

```
url(/foo/bar.png) --> url(/foo/bar.png) [unchanged]
url(foo/bar.png) --> url(/path/to/file/foo/bar.png) [made absolute]
url("foo/bar.png") --> url(/path/to/file/foo/bar.png) [made absolute, no quotes]
url('foo/bar.png') --> url(/path/to/file/foo/bar.png) [made absolute, no quotes]
```

I tried many different patterns, including a lookahead for / and many variations of the below.

```
$dir = dirname($path);
$r = preg_replace('#url\(("|\')?([^/"\']{1}.+)("|\')?\)#', "url(/$dir/$2)", $contents);
```

Can't seem to get it right. Any help?

Comment: Why not just put them in same directory as css and skip all paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should do it:

```
$r = preg_replace('#url\(("|\'|)([^/"\'\)][^"\'\)]*)("|\'|)\)#', 'url(/'.$dir.'/$2)', $contents);
```

Comment: Works. Didn't realize you could do "(a|b|)". Thanks.

Comment: More faster, same result: $r = preg_replace('#url\([\'"]?([^"\'\)]+)[\'"]?\)#', 'url(/'.$dir.'/$1)', $contents);

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify two things. First for matching quotes, you should use `["']?` rather than a group. And for detecting a relative path name, check for the presence of a letter rather than the absence of a slash.

```
preg_replace('#url\(  [\'"]?  (\w[^)"\']+)  [\'"]?  \)#x'
```

I'm using `)` to detect the end of the braces rather than `.+`. Though it would be more robust to list only allowed characters like `[\w/.]+`

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
$pattern = '#url\([\'"]?(\w[\w\./]+)[\'"]?\)#i';

$subjects = array(
  'url(/foo/bar.png)',
  'url(foo/bar.png)',
  'url("foo/bar.png")',
  'url(\'foo/bar.png\')',
);

foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
  echo "$subject => ", preg_replace($pattern, "url(/path/to/$1)", $subject), "\n";
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
url(/foo/bar.png) => url(/foo/bar.png)
url(foo/bar.png) => url(/path/to/foo/bar.png)
url("foo/bar.png") => url(/path/to/foo/bar.png)
url('foo/bar.png') => url(/path/to/foo/bar.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = dirname($path);
$r = preg_replace('#url\(([\'"]?)([^/].*?)\1\)#', "url(/{$dir}/$2)", $contents);
```

- match `url`
- match open paren
- open capture group 1
- match ' or " zero or once
- close capturing group 1
- open capturing group 2
- match one character that is not a /
- match zero or more characters ungreedily
- close capturing group 2
- match whatever was captured in capturing group 1 (this ensures a same-quote match, and works if there is no quote captured by 1)
- match a close paren

Capturing group 2 contains the target data.

Comment: Didn't know you could use references in patterns. Doesn't work though.. Results in eg
background: url(/foo/bar/"/images/image.png")

Comment: Hmm worked for me.. let me see if I spilled a little bit when I pasted.

Comment: Nope, works for me. Not getting the quotes. If you adjusted it in any way, adding parentheses someplace, then the $2 might have to change to another capturing group. Here's what I get from my test output: `background: url("foo/bar.png") => background: url(/J:\PROJECTS\PhpTestProject1/foo/bar.png)`. One thing to note is that `$dir = dirname(__FILE__);` may not work so well on Windows in this situation. :-P

Comment: Weird. The quotes are always included in $2, which makes sense since $2 is greedy, $1 and $2 are not.

Comment: $2 == `([^/].*?)` which is not greedy, except for the first character. I tested that on `url('')`, though, and it was not a match. Probably just something you are doing different that I am not. In any case, works for me. :-)